# Counter in BruteForce while-loop; Out of memory with yield?

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn basic programming with python, and as I encountered permutations, I wanted to see if I could (for fun) brute force a userinput..

It seems to work for short PW's, but my counter seems to have a flaw, or do I miss something about permutations nature? ...the counter shows the same number each time, for any PW of the same length...

Also, there's a memory error for longer PW's, but I thought I ruled that out by using a generator(yield) instead of a list.. or didn't I?

Thanks for your Help

```
import string
from itertools import permutations

characters = string.ascii_letters
user_pw = input('Set your PW')
attempts = 0
done = False

while True:
    def Generator():
        guess_storage = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(characters, len(user_pw))]
        for current in guess_storage:
            yield current


    for guess in Generator():
        attempts += 1
        if guess == user_pw:
            print('SUCESS: ')
            print('Password: ', guess)
        done = True

    if done == True:
        break

print('Attempts: ', attempts)
```

Comment: Why are you redefining `Generator` in every iteration? Move the function definition out of the `while True` loop

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Good point, classic rookie!

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with the memory error. By doing:

```
guess_storage = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(characters, len(user_pw))]
```

you are 'gluing' all the generated permutations back into a single list before then iterating over that list. this is where you run out of memory.  Instead, try making a generator to be iterated over:

```
guess_storage = (''.join(p) for p in permutations(characters, len(user_pw)))
```

Or don't use a generator, and just `join` each permutation as it is yielded (see below).

Next, you are doing this all in a while loop (including the generator), but this is unnecessary and inefficient. Just build the Generator once, then when you are looping over every guess from the generator, just break out when it finds a match.

A (shorter) way of writing what I think you intended is:

```
def Generator():
    for current in permutations(characters, len(user_pw)):
        yield ''.join(current)

for guess in Generator():
    print("Guessing", guess)  # To show the guesses in action
    attempts += 1
    if guess == user_pw:
        print('SUCCESS: ')
        print('Password: ', guess)
        print('Attempts: ', attempts)
        break
```

You can also avoid manually tracking the attempts counter by using:

```
for attempts, guess in enumerate(Generator()):
```

Comment: Probably just a style thing but I would write `for current in permutations(characters, len(user_pw)): yield ''.join(current)`. I think it is neatier.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I agree - was just making that change when you commented!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Brilliant answer, and quick! 

I'm not shure I get, why my counter wasn't working, but I get, why this solution makes much more sense!